# Add/remove CSS will cause IE9 to increase the table's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I add a mouse event to the HTML TR when user mouse-over/out the TR to change some CSS color. But in IE9 seems to have an issue that the table's height will keep increasing each time the CSS changed.

Note: the issue only occurs when the horizontal scrollbar appears.

Here is the HTML.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-body">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:3040px;" class="item">
                            <div>
                                Please mouse-over me and out
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="item">
                            <div>
                                Please mouse-over me and out
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('.item').mouseover(function () {
     $(this).parent().addClass("item-over");
 }).mouseout(function() {
     $(this).parent().removeClass("item-over");
 });
 }
);
```

Here is the CSS setting

```
 html, body {height:100%}
 body {
     margin: 0; padding: 0 5px;
 }
 div.grid {
     background: #DAE7F6; border: 1px solid #86A4BE; overflow: hidden; zoom: 1;
 }
 div.grid-body {
     background: red; border: 0; overflow: auto; width: 100%; position: relative;
 }
 tr.item-over {
     color: #6eadff;
 }
```

You can run the full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzWfP/).

Comment: After 9 versions, IE still can't get it right :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's another possible fix that also seems to work in my case.

Setting ANY margin (top, right, bottom, left, or any combination) to 'auto' seems to solve it.

```
div.grid-body {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Or:

```
div.grid-body {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Etc.

Comment: nice... I had this issue today and spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong until I found this.

Comment: I have no idea why this fixes it, but thank you for finding it.

Comment: Ive spend whole day trying to solve "overflow-auto, height growth bug" occuring only on IE9. THIS IS THE SOLUTION!

Comment: Nice one. Christ IE is a joke.

Answer (score 8):

Another possible fix suggested in the blog post [IE9 Hover Bug Workaround](http://blog.brianrichards.net/post/6721471926/ie9-hover-bug-workaround):

```
div.grid-body {
    min-height: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone came here looking for a fix for datatables jquery plugin, the proper class to add this fix to is:

```
.dataTables_scrollBody
{
    margin-top:auto;
}
```

Took a bit of digging to find the proper div, so I figured I would try to save someone time.

Answer (score 1):

I might have just solved it.

Try:

```
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
```

on the containing element ("div.grid-body" in this case).

Comment: Also see my other answer, which might have fewer side-effects.

Comment: Mysteriously, this solved my issue with the same problem, in this case I added the container that had overflow: auto; dynamically through jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It stops doing it and yet does the mouse hover effect by setting:

```
 div.grid-body {
     background: red; border: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; position: relative;
 }
```

instead of overflow:auto. Mabe you'd prefer to use overflow:scroll or visible. And make it trigger this as an extra property only for the IE9 case.

Comment: We can't change the overflow setting, because we don't know how web developer to use the grid in their application, we have to count on the overflow:auto to depend on browser's behavior. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You have as well quite inline css in your html (the customer might not like that), and in one table, you have style="table-layout:fixed;. Looks like it also removes the issue removing it: Try playing with other possible value.

Comment: In real case, it has two table, one for header and one for content, in that example, I just remove some unrelated code to clarify the issue.

Comment: i dont have ie9, so i dont have to test this,
but try using ".toggleClass(ClassName)" instead of .addClass(ClassName), it saved me some problems before.

Answer (score 0):

Open Developer tools and remove the table-layout:fixed rule from the table that is the child of grid-body. it should work may be.

Comment: but the table-layout:fixed cannot remove for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

remove with form the first 'TD' element `<td style="width:3040px;"`. It will help.

Do you need so huge "td" there ?

Comment: Yes, I need it because I used it to simulate the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

just to see

> div.grid {
>            background: #DAE7F6; border: 1px solid #86A4BE; overflow: hidden;
>   zoom: 1;
>           width:100%;
>        }

```
what about this:
    width:100% !important;
```

Comment: I tested with your suggestion, but it didn't work on IE9 browser.

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the overflow try this

div.grid-body {
     background: red; border: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; position: relative;
 }

else

change your script to this  (the problem is in the add/remove class)

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
   $('.item').mouseover(function () {
      $(this).parent("tr").css("color", "#6eadff");
     }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).parent("tr").css("color","#000");
   });
 });
```

Comment: Using overflow:hidden can avoid this issue, but it will break the scrollbar functionality if the content is exceeded its height. Any idea? or do you want us to check its height when any other property has changed? (I am afraid it may introduce an IE performance issue)

Answer (score 0):

why do you do it with JS and not with the css?
i.e:

```
.grid-body table tr:hover {background:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just "memorize" the height of the element in a variable when the mouseover event is fired, and then set it back to that value again when the mouseout event is fired.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('.item').mouseover(function () {
     // store the height in a variabile (keep also in mind margins and paddings)
     $(this).parent().addClass("item-over");
 }).mouseout(function() {
     $(this).parent().removeClass("item-over");
     // now set back the original height
 });
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

should work to just add a fixed height to the table row

so the containing table row reads:
      `<tr height="50px">`

you can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/f3TDb/

I'm assuming that you're not doing it wisth divs and css:hover for a specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

i realize i'm months behind on this, but this stumped me yesterday and found this thread. hopefully my answer helps:

it's the `overflow: auto` in `div.grid-body` that's messing things up. you'll have to change this to `scroll`, possibly:

```
div.grid-body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

if you don't want the vertical scrollbars.

note that you'll have to code your js to determine if you need a scrollbar so you can set `overflow-x` to `visible` (the default) if there are no overflows and `scroll` if there are, simulating `auto`.